# Execute shell script which is encrypted with openssl enc

Tags: shell, encryption, openssl, sh

I have a bash script which I need to encrypt(Run the script without anybody seeing the code.).

I have tried encrypting with command `openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -in test.sh > testing`.

I can execute the script with command:

```
openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -in testing -pass pass:<password> | sh -
```

But my script needs arguments as well, how to pass arguments to the encrypted script?

Original execution method: `sh test.sh 1 a 23`

How to execute encrypted script with arguments "1 a 23"?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no bash involved in your code. You run the script with sh, not bash.

Comment: once the script is encrypted and named as testing, it cannot be executed as "sh testing". We need to execute it with openssl only. The prob is to pass the arguments to the script while executing it.

Comment: Well, if you want to run it as bash, you can do a `... | bash`. This is unrelated to encryption. In the **original** execution method (unencrypted), you don't run it as bash either. That's why I find it confusing that you tagged this question as `sh` **and** `bash`. I suggest that you remove the _bash_ tag for clarity.

Comment: Just thinking that it is not entirely clear what you want to achieve. When you do a `openssl enc ...`, you get an encrypted form of the input file. To execute the encrypted script file, you would have to decrypt it first. Then you can of course pass arguments to the decrypted script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly tell `sh` to read the commands from stdin, and the specify the arguments:

```
openssl ... | sh -s 1 a 23
```

Comment: how to source the openssl encrypted file? `openssl ... | source -s 1 a 23` doesnt work.

Comment: @Nikita: I find your comment confusing: You tagged your question as `sh`, but AFIK neither POSIX shell nor Bourne shell do have a command named `source`. See [here](https://shellhaters.org/) for a list of the commands available to such a shell. For sourcing code, you have the command [`.`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18) This is similar to the `source` command in bash, ksh or zsh, but it does not read from stdin.